# Whats wrong with the code (redirecting which href)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this function:

```js
function redirect() {
  document.getElementById("starSign").getAttribute('href');
  window.location.href = href + "#" + $("input[name='sign']:checked").val() +
    $("input[name='period']:checked").val();
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="period" value="Week" id="week" />
      <b>weekly</b>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <table cellpadding="10">
        <tr>
          <th><input type="radio" value="Aries" name="sign" id="Aries" /> Aries</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a id=starSign value="Aries" href="Aries.html"> <img src="Aries.jpg" alt="Aries" /></a>
          </td>
        </tr>


<button onclick=redirect()>click here to get the horoscope</button>
```

I try to redirect to `Aries.html#AriesWeek` through the function and nothing happens. Can I do `redirect(href)` also?

Comment: ```document.getElementById("getSign")``` is returning your ```table``` element, not the ```a``` element deeper in the DOM. Put an ```id``` attribute on your ```a``` and get that element instead. Also, make sure to assign ```href = getAttribute('href')```

Comment: When is `redirect()` even called?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are getting `href` value but you never store it into any variable for further use.

```js
function redirect() {
  var href = document.getElementById("starSign").getAttribute('href');
  window.location.href = href + "#" + $("input[name='sign']:checked").val() +
    $("input[name='period']:checked").val();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="period" value="Week" id="week" />
      <b>weekly</b>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <table cellpadding="10">
        <tr>
          <th><input type="radio" value="Aries" name="sign" id="Aries" /> Aries</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a id=starSign value="Aries" href="Aries.html"> <img src="Aries.jpg" alt="Aries" /></a>
          </td>
        </tr>


<button onclick=redirect()>click here to get the horoscope</button>
```